# How to Remove Brackets and Quotes

Tags: python

How do to remove Brackets and Quotes which is display when variable result is called in the label below.

```
sql = "SELECT question FROM questions WHERE id='1'"
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchone()enter code here
print  result
# print(result)
root6 = Tk()

root6.title("EVALUATION -FORM")
root6.geometry("450x300")
var6 = IntVar()


# disconnect from server
db.close()
k = Label(root6, text=result)
k.pack()
k.place(x=20, y=15)
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and -- particularly -- put some care and attention into building a [mcve] (right now, this code doesn't run on its own, so someone else can't see the problem for themselves and so can't test whether their proposed fix actually works).

Comment: If your question is about how Tk is rendering something, it would be helpful to provide either a screenshot or a detailed textual description (with the exact string) of what's being rendered (or, ideally, both).

Answer (score 1):

Using my powers of ESP to answer an inadequately-asked question:

You're getting something like `("This is the question",)` or `["This is the question"]` printed because the return from `fetchone()` is a list or tuple, not a string.

This is because `fetchone()` returns the first *row of results* from your database query, and a row is inherently a sequence type, able to contain multiple items. If you had selected multiple columns, that row would need to contain multiple fields, so the datatype returned is a sequence, able to contain such multiple fields -- thus making handling database results more consistent than it would be if the type of the returned values varied by the number of columns present in each row.

---

Consider:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row is None:
  print 'ERROR: No question with id 1 found in the database'
  sys.exit()
result = row[0]
print result
```